# Нейминг в юзер контролах xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, usercontrol

Создал юзер контрол для валидации пароля в Xamarin, в форме есть `Entry` и `Label` для отображения ошибок пароля, например, символов недостаточно и тд. Использую я его в нескольких вьюшках следующим образом:

```xml
<controls:PasswordEntry
    PasswordText="{Binding Password}"
    PasswordError="{Binding PasswordError}"
    IsPasswordIncorrect="{Binding PasswordIncorrect}"
    Grid.Row="1" />
```

Код выше работает отлично, но если `PasswordText != "Password"`, то все ломается, следующий код уже не работает

```xml
<controls:PasswordEntry Grid.Row="1"
     PasswordText="{Binding NewPassword}"
     PasswordError="{Binding NewPasswordError}"
     IsPasswordIncorrect="{Binding NewPasswordIncorrect}"/>
```

Это вынужденная мера, т.к. в одной форме я использую несколько юзер контролов. Код юзер контрола:

```xml
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Frame x:Name="PasswordFrame" Padding="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Entry Grid.Row="0"
                       x:Name="Password"
                       Text="{Binding Password}"
                       IsPassword="True" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       x:Name="PasswordErrorLabel"
                       TextColor="{DynamicResource ErrorColor}"
                       Padding="2" />
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

```cs
public string PasswordText {
    get => (string) GetValue(PasswordTextProperty);
    set => SetValue(PasswordTextProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty PasswordTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    "PasswordText",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(PasswordEntry),
    "",
    BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanged: PasswordTextPropertyChanged);
```

По моему мнению, это не работает из за нейминга, т.е. ели поле не Password, а например Password1, или PasswordF, то ничего не работает

Comment: О каком именно поле вы говорите? О поле в VM или View? К чему именно у вас привязка? Вы говорите о значении поля или имени поля?

Comment: В view  я привязываю поле 'Password' в VM, если это поле называется не 'Password', а любым другим именем, то ничего не работает

Comment: А вы при этом меняете Binding? `{Binding Password}`

Comment: Да. В первом куске кода видно